# cgo godefs and Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, go

I write a program on GoLang with inclusion Objective-C code (call some OSX API) via `C` GoLang's package and I need to pass variable of type `T` from Go code to Objective-C code and vice versa. `T` is structure (or other type). So I need to create compatible (in terms of memory layout) type/variable in GoLang and pass it to Objective-C via `unsafe.Pointer` casting. For generic C code I use `godefs` in such cases, but I unable to use `godefs` for Objective-C. If I try `go tool cgo -godefs cgodefs.go`

```
// This is "cgodefs.go" file
package tmp

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -x objective-c
#cgo LDFLAGS: -framework Cocoa
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
*/
import "C"

type CGPoint C.CGPoint
```

I receive tons of errors:

```
In file included from /Users/unsacrificed/go/src/gui/cgodefs.go:10:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Headers/Cocoa.h:12:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:8:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:503:1: error: expected identifier or '('
@class NSString, Protocol;
^
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:505:9: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
typedef NSString * NSExceptionName NS_EXTENSIBLE_STRING_ENUM;
        ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:506:9: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
typedef NSString * NSRunLoopMode NS_EXTENSIBLE_STRING_ENUM;
... (100000+ lines of errors)
```

Interested thing is that I can compile and run GoLang apps with Objective-C via `C` GoLang's package.

I [report](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23615) to GoLang but he says that

> The cgo tool works with C, not Objective-C.

Is there any way to get GoLang equivalent (memory compatible) type for Objective-C type?

Comment: Not sure I understand which direction you're trying to interoperate in, but anything that you can do in C, you can do in ObjC. (The reverse is not true, however.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. It is possible to do what I want. The only thing I missed: `godefs` ignores `#cgo CFLAGS: -x objective-c` line. Solution - pass required CFLAGS to `go` binary as arguments (`-- -x objective-c`).
Working example:

```
// +build ignore

package tmp

//go:generate go tool cgo -godefs -- -x objective-c cgodefs.go

//#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
import "C"

type CGPoint C.CGPoint
```

output:

```
// Created by cgo -godefs - DO NOT EDIT
// cgo -godefs -- -x objective-c cgodefs.go

package tmp

type CGPoint struct {
    X   float64
    Y   float64
}
```